Google Sheets: Need to Paste Formatting
I have a Google Sheet that has all of the data on the first main sheet. I don't know a lot about scripts which is why I have all of the scripts separate.
Script 1. I have a script that I run that creates new tabs named after the information in Column A.
Script 2. I have another script that I run to freeze the first row of each of the sheets made from script 1 above
Script 3. I have a third script that I run to resize all of the rows.
I would like to figure out how to:
4. Copy the formatting from the first, main sheet to the sheets that are automatically created with script (1). To be clear, I am not pasting any values - just the formatting.
5. Delete all extra columns and delete all but 3 extra rows
6. Is there a way to have it alphabetize the tabs created in script 1? Right now I have to sort the main sheet by the Column A data, run script 1, then re-sort it by last name (Column D). I'd like to not have to repeatedly resort, but it's not critical to my success.
I'm not opposed to all scripts running at once, instead of being separate, I just wasn't sure how to smush it all together.
My google sheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME26lkh6F552uRQ3vl9Fv-BPIc2bpM_GlYxWCVoPkVA/edit?usp=sharing
Script 1 has already been run on this sheet (the new tabs have been created)
Script 1 (new tabs):
function makeTabs2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("All");
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();//identifies the last active row on the sheet
 
  for (var i = 1; i < last; i++) {
 
    var tabName = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).getValue();//get the range in column A and get the value. 
    try {
      if (ss.getSheetByName(tabName) == null) {
        var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);//create a new sheet with the value
        // this is the addition to add the formula to the new tab   
    ss.getSheetByName(tabName).getRange("A1").setFormula('QUERY(All!A1:R,"select * where upper(A) = \'' + tabName.toUpperCase() + '\'",1)');
 
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err);
 
    }
  }
}

Script 2 (freeze top row):
function freezeRowsAndColumns() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
}

Script 3 (resize all rows):
 function resizeAllrows() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var requests = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => {
      return {
        updateDimensionProperties: {
          properties: { pixelSize: 50 },
          range: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), dimension: "ROWS" },
          fields: "pixelSize"
        }
      }
    });
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, ss.getId());
  }

Any/all help would be appreciated.
I have tested several variations of code I've found on here with no luck.

Use CopyTo copyTo

In your question, are 3 questions included? 1. Copy the formatting from the first, main sheet to the sheets that are automatically created with script (1). To be clear, I am not pasting any values - just the formatting.. 2. Delete all extra columns and delete all but 3 extra rows 3. Is there a way to have it alphabetize the tabs created in script 1? Right now I have to sort the main sheet by the Column A data, run script 1, then re-sort it by last name (Column D). I'd like to not have to repeatedly resort, but it's not critical to my success..

I can resolve your 1st question. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your 2nd and 3rd questions. By this, I cannot propose a modified script. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the details of your 2nd and 3rd questions? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

To clarify the 2nd question: when script 1 runs, it makes new sheets that have columns A through Z, but we only have information through column R. I want to delete the empty columns S-Z.  Same for the rows, except each new sheet has a different number of rows based on the data being pulled. If you look at the first generated sheet, "Clay/Cohn", there are 20 rows of data. I would want to delete rows 24-1000, so that there are only 3 extra blank rows below the data. On the next sheet, "Beard", there are 31 rows of data. So I would want to delete rows 35-1000

To clarify the 3rd question: when script 1 ran, it generated the tabs at the bottom in the order that they're on the "All spreadsheet." Ideally, I'd like the tabs that are generated to be alphabetical. The only way I know to do this is to manually re-sort the "All" sheet to be alphabetical by column A, run script 1, and then re-sort the "All" sheet the way I want it (by column D, then E)

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to copy the cell format including the row height and column width to the new sheet.
You want to leave columns "A" to "R". And, you want to delete other columns after column "S".
You want to sort the new sheets in the alphabetical order.

Modification points:

In your script, getValue() is used in a loop. In this case, I thought that first, all values are retrieved from column "A" outside of the loop. This can be used to sort the new sheets in the alphabetical order.
In order to copy the cell format including the row height and column width, I thought that the combination of copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet and clearContents() of Class Sheet might be able to be used.
In order to delete after column "S", after the sheet was copied, this can be run.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script 1:
In this modification, your script was modified.
function makeTabs2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("All");

  // --- I modified the below script.
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName());
  var values = [...new Set(sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a]) => a))].sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
  values.forEach(tabName => {
    try {
      if (!sheets.includes(tabName)) {
        var create = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(tabName).clearContents();
        create.deleteColumns(19, create.getMaxColumns() - 18);
        create.getRange("A1").setFormula('QUERY(All!A1:R,"select * where upper(A) = \'' + tabName.toUpperCase() + '\'",1)');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err.stack);
    }
  });
}

Modified script 2:
When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the number of sheets for copying is 94. In this case, I'm worried that the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) might not be able to be used because of the maximum execution time. So, as another modification, I propose to use Sheets API.
When you use this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.
function makeTabs3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("All");
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName());
  var values = [...new Set(sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([a]) => a))].sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
  var requests = values
    .filter(s => !sheets.includes(s))
    .flatMap((tabName, i) => {
      const newSheetId = `12345${i + 1}`;
      return [
        { duplicateSheet: { sourceSheetId: sheetId, insertSheetIndex: i + 1, newSheetName: tabName, newSheetId } },
        { deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId: newSheetId, dimension: "COLUMNS", startIndex: 18 } } },
        { repeatCell: { fields: "userEnteredValue", range: { sheetId: newSheetId } } },
        { updateCells: { range: { sheetId: newSheetId, startRowIndex: 0, endRowIndex: 1, startColumnIndex: 0, endColumnIndex: 1 }, rows: [{ values: [{ userEnteredValue: { formulaValue: `=QUERY(All!A1:R,"select * where upper(A) = '${tabName.toUpperCase()}'",1)` } }] }], fields: "userEnteredValue" } }
      ]
    });
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}


When I tested this script using your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the processing time was about 90 seconds.

References:

copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet
clearContents() of Class Sheet
Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate

